# table footnote indentation

Tags: tables, footnotes, indentation, threeparttable, tablenotes

[flushleft] makes the whole table flushleft. I only want the footnotes to be indented with the beginning of the table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{+}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}#1\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\sisetup{detect-all}
\begin{table}
\caption{Data of Pareto optimals of symmetrical Steffen flexible polyhedra}
\centering \label{table:StefResultAppen}
\begin{tabular}{+l^c^c^l^c^c^c^c^c^c}
\toprule[0.06em] 
& Result&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Objectives}&\multicolumn{5}{c}{Parameters} & \\
& Index&$\Theta$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$R$} & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$ & $e$ & \\ \midrule
\rowstyle{\bfseries}& J&\ang{10.4} & 0.34  & 8.1383 & 5.7008 & 5.5161 & 8.5020& 8.5\\
\bottomrule[0.06em]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoSteffen}. 
\item Results labelled in letters A$\sim$J are from Table~\ref{table:StefResult} and are presented in bold font.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your *mwe* is not complete. missing are some packages and `\begin{document}` also your document class is not available.

Answer (score 1):

your table is no consistent:

- table notes are intended to use in `threeparttable`
- number of defined columns is bigger than used
- sorry, but it is not clear, how you like to have aligned table notes. consequently examples below can not be very helpfull
- also used document class is not public know, so in *mwe* below i usee standard `book`
- your problems seems to has source in definition of `\rowstyle{\bfseries}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{book}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\newcolumntype{+}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}#1\ignorespaces}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\sisetup{detect-all}

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{table notes with \texttt{threeparttable}}
\centering \label{table:StefResultAppen}
\begin{tabular}{+l @{} ^c ^c ^l ^c ^c ^c ^c ^c}
\toprule[0.06em]
& Result    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Objectives}&\multicolumn{5}{c}{Parameters}  \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-9}
& Index     &$\Theta$   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$R$}
                        & $a$   & $b$    & $c$    & $d$    & $e$            \\
    \midrule
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
& J         &\ang{10.4} & 0.34  & 8.1383 & 5.7008 & 5.5161 & 8.5020 & 8.5   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\item All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoSteffen}.
\item Results labelled in letters A$\sim$J are from Table~\ref{table:StefResult} and are presented in bold font.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{table notes without \texttt{threeparttable}}
\label{table:StefResultAppen}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{+l @{} ^c ^c ^l ^c ^c ^c ^c ^c}
\toprule[0.06em]
& Result    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Objectives}&\multicolumn{5}{c}{Parameters}  \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-9}
& Index     &$\Theta$   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$R$}
                        & $a$   & $b$    & $c$    & $d$    & $e$            \\
    \midrule
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
& J         &\ang{10.4} & 0.34  & 8.1383 & 5.7008 & 5.5161 & 8.5020 & 8.5   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hspace*{\tabcolsep}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\item All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoSteffen}.
\item Results labelled in letters A$\sim$J are from Table~\ref{table:StefResult} and are presented in bold font.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{table notes in multi column cells}
\label{table:StefResultAppen}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{+l @{} ^c ^c ^l ^c ^c ^c ^c ^c}
\toprule[0.06em]
& Result    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Objectives}&\multicolumn{5}{c}{Parameters}  \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-9}
& Index     &$\Theta$   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$R$}
                        & $a$   & $b$    & $c$    & $d$    & $e$            \\
    \midrule
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
& J         &\ang{10.4} & 0.34  & 8.1383 & 5.7008 & 5.5161 & 8.5020 & 8.5   \\
    \bottomrule
%\hspace*{\tabcolsep}
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\footnotesize
All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoSteffen}.
                    }\\
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\footnotesize
Results labelled in letters A$\sim$J are from Table~\ref{table:StefResult} and are presented in bold font.
                    }
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]